# closing all jquery accordian tabs

Tags: jquery

I previously posted a question regarding a simple jquery accordian, the answer I received helped but the question I am asking now is the follow up to that question. Not sure how you would you make the tabs collapsible so that they all close. Click on Welcome to read, click on it again to close it. At present one of the tabs is left open.
This is the code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#va-accordion .va-content').hide();
           $('.va-heading').click(function(){
                   $('#va-accordion .va-content').slideUp();
                   $(this).next().slideDown();
                   return false;
           });

});
```

This is the [link](http://www.photorestorationexpert.co.uk/testFolder/cbIndex.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.va-content').slideUp();
```

closes all tabs

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow check the state of the accordion, before actually sliding it up or sliding it down, to define which of those actions to perform.

A simple if-statement that checks whether the accordion is open or not, solves the problem.

You seem to be on the right track, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Test to see whether the content div is visible prior to calling `slideUp()`.  If it is, don't call `slideDown()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#va-accordion .va-content').hide();
    $('.va-heading').click(function() {
        var contentDiv = $(this).next();
        var isVisible = contentDiv.is(":visible");
        $('#va-accordion .va-content').slideUp();
        if (!isVisible) contentDiv.slideDown();
        return false;
    });

});
```